# MongoDb conditional UpdateMany statement including expression using .net driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fc232d9b9b390623ce498ee"
},
"trigger": {
    "type": 0,
    "interval": 15
},
"startTime": {
    "$numberLong": "1608078905"
},
"state": 0,
"assigned_to": ""
}
```

And I have a UpdateMany statement that only updates documents that their startTime (timespan) + interval (seconds) is lower than equal to the current timestamp with the value of 'computer a', (UPDATE) and set the 'state' attribute to '1':

(UPDATE)

```
db.mycollection.updateMany(
{ state: 0 },
[
  { $set: { assigned_to: { $switch: { 
    branches: [ 
      { case: { $lte: [ { $add: [ "$startTime", "$trigger.interval" ] }, new Timestamp() ] }, then: "computer a" }
    ],
    default: ""
  } } } },
  { $set: { state: 1 } }
  ]
)
```

My goals are:

1. (RESOLVED) To update the state to '1' in addition to the 'assigned_to' field
2. (RESOLVED) To automatically calculate the timestamp (the current time)
3. Eventually, to have it working with my C# .NET Core application (if possible - with the driver syntax so it will be strongly-typed)

On the C# side I've tried the following (with no success):

```
var results = _jobs.UpdateMany(
    f => (f.StartTime + f.Trigger.Interval) <= DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
    o => o.AssignedTo == "computer a");
```

Another approach I tried:

```
        var builder = Builders<Job>.Filter;

        var filters =
            builder.Lte(o => o.StartTime + o.Trigger.Interval, DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()) &
            builder.Eq(o => o.AssignedTo, string.Empty);

        var updateDefinition = 
            Builders<Job>.Update.Set(x => x.AssignedTo, Environment.MachineName);

        var result = _jobs.UpdateMany(filters, updateDefinition);
```

After spending hours, I only achieve the UpdateMany statement above working.
If you have ideas about how it could be done in a better way - I'm free for offers.

Comment: You can assign/update multiple fields within the `$set`. (1) This means "update the state to '1' in addition to the 'assigned_to' field" is to specify another field within the `$set`. (2) _"To automatically calculate the timestamp"_: you specify the timestamp calculation within the `$set`. What is the calculation look like? (I am not a c# coder).

Comment: (1) will give it a shot - thanks! (2) this is more related to mongo - is there a way to tell mongo "new Date()" but store it in timestamp and not as "date" object? (my goal is to store the current timestamp instead of calculating it and send it explicitly)

Comment: MongoDB has data types both as `Date` and `Timestamps`; see [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/bson-types/index.html).

Comment: thanks again! it's working and I updated the original question. Now I only left with the C# part :)